# How to pass multiple values using same parameter in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

The website I am working on has many textboxes, after filling all the boxes I have to click on Add and repeat the same filling again on the same screen. How can I Pass the different sets of values without closing the browser using TestNG.

```
set 1:
Name = harry
jobid =123
occumpation = PA
```

Click on add button and on the same page repeat the below

```
Set 2:
Name = john
jobid = 125
occumpation = PA
```

Comment: You can use dataProviderin testNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TestNG data provider.

```
@Test(dataProvider="webSiteData")
public void myTestCase(String name, String jobId, String occupation)
{
   //Your test code goes here...
}

@DataProvider(name="webSiteData")
public Object[][] getData()
{
   Object [][] myData = {{"harry","123","PA"},
                         {"john","125","PA"}};
   return myData;
}
```

Note: Here each row of myData represents the number of times this test method will be executed. The column represents the parameters to pass to test method. So two rows mean your test method will be executed two times with two different sets of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestNG Data provider, 
Reference: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/
 OR https://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html

Comment: This should be comment , giving answer without explanation should be avoided and removed from answer.